# Displays WHERE for two conditions in the same column

Tags: php, database

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|   id  |   posts_id    |   users_id    |   ratings |
-----------------------------------------------------
|   1   |       7       |       20      |   5       |
|   2   |       8       |       20      |   3       |
|   3   |       7       |       21      |   4       |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Table name: **mytable**

\I want to make sure that ratings between posts_id and users_id are matched on the same column.

```
$query = $conn->query("SELECT ratings FROM mytable WHERE posts_id=7 and users_id=20");
$row = $query->fetch_array();
echo $row['ratings'];
```

This query does not work. I know there must be something wrong.

I want to get results: **5**

What is the best query to show ratings?

----------------**UPDATE**-----------------------------

Sorry, my first problem lies with the connection, and now it is resolved.

But now there is a new problem.

I want to display the total sum of the rating results.

**My new code**

```
$Rate = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE posts_id=7");

while ($Rated = $Rate->fetch_array()) {
    echo $Rated['ratings'] + $Rated['ratings'];
    }
```

For example on `posts_id=7`

Here I expect `5 + 4 = 9`

But my code results exactly `54 + 54`

How to fix this code?

Comment: Is there any error output?  That query should work, at least from looking at it at a high level.

Comment: Your `and` should be `AND`.

Comment: Your code working fine.write this line.` error_reporting(-1);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and post your error here.

Comment: Nidhi, has the right answer. The "AND" shouldn't matter if it is "and"

Comment: Hello all. I have updated my question, please see. thank you

Comment: I would use MySQL to retrieve the `SUM` like so: `SELECT SUM(ratings) as total_ratings FROM mytable WHERE posts_id=7` Which would result in a single row with the total.

Comment: Does the table have to add the total_ratings column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the updated question, this code should be work. We can use sum() function. Check here [sum() function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-sum-function.htm)

```
$Rate = $conn->query("SELECT sum(ratings) as ratings FROM mytable WHERE posts_id=7");

while ($Rated = $Rate->fetch_array()) {
    echo $Rated['ratings'];
}
```

Comment: Yes .. This is very helpful. But I need to change also the `echo $Rated['ratings'];` Becomes `echo $Rated['SUM(ratings)'];`